# Must variadic template have callable specialization with non empty parameter pack to be well-formed?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

On the one hand there is the rule [[temp.res]/8.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8.3) which states that if every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack the program is ill-formed and no diagnostic is required. On the other hand one can imagine the situation when one can explicit instantiate any desired specialization of the template but cannot call it [[temp.mem]/5.note-1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.mem#5.note-1), e.g.:

```
struct foo {
    template <class... Ts>
    foo() { }
};

template
foo::foo<int, float, double>();
```

Is the code well-formed or the fact one cannot call any valid specialization apart from the one with empty template parameter pack violates the [temp.res]/8.3 rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reminds me a little of the Haskell function [`absurd`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/void-0.5.10/docs/src/Data-Void.html#absurd):

```
-- | Since 'Void' values logically don't exist, this witnesses the logical
-- reasoning tool of \"ex falso quodlibet\".
absurd :: Void -> a
```

What this means is a function that takes an instance of `Void` and returns an instance of *any type*. What does it mean to say that a function can invent an instance of any type out of thin air from nothing? It doesn't matter, because you can't come up with an instance of `Void` to pass into it.

Similarly here. In my opinion, the code is well-formed, if silly. There is nothing here that **requires** `Ts...` to be an empty pack. If `Ts...` were non-empty, the program would still be fine. The fact that there's no way to make `Ts...` non-empty seems orthogonal - if you could come up with a construct that made a non-empty `Ts` that led to the program being ill-formed, maybe [temp.res]/8.3 would apply - but you can't so... `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`